# Weird behavior between pyramid and python's requests library

Tags: python, pyramid, python-requests

So I'm trying to create a system to index users in a search database, but pyramid and the requests library are failing me. This is the piece of code messing up:

```
requests.put('http://localhost:9200/master/user/%s' % str(session.query(User).filter(User.username == request.params['username']).first().user_id)
, data = '{"name" : %s, "reputation" : 0, "username" : %s}' % (str(request.params['name']), str(request.params['username']))
```

)

It works in the python interpreter fine, but in the view, it keeps returning a 400 status. I do run `session.flush()` before this line of code. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Like you can see in the code sample of J.F. Sebastian, you put too much code in the same line. This make it hard to debug. Spread this using variables. Then you can log/print stuff to help debug.

Comment: Also, note that your JSON will be invalid because you did not add quotes around the "%s". Again, like J.F. Sebastian showed, you should use json.dumps to make sure you create valid JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user = session.query(User).filter_by(username=request.params['username']).first()
if user is None:
   "not found" # do whatever appropriate in your case e.g., return 404

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
requests.put('http://localhost:9200/master/user/{userid}'.format(user.user_id),
             data=json.dumps(dict(name=request.params['name'], reputation=0,
                                  username=request.params['username'])),
             headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been pulling my hair out over this.